# How to add Engine.Razor reference in a windows service in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, razor, service

I am unable to add `System.Web.Razor` reference in a windows service. Added below code in `app.config` and added the .DLL reference in references folder also but getting error when trying to send emails from windows service.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.6.0.0" newVersion="3.6.0.0"/></dependentAssembly>
```

Getting below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: This may be due to the fact that they are used by different target frameworks

Comment: I want to know if we can use Razor engine in a windows service. Because the reference says System.Web.Razor

Comment: Question, why do you want to use Razor in a Windows Service?  You potentially, could but you have to pull in the entire `System.Web` in older versions, or if you follow the latest technology `.Net Standard / Asp.Net Core` you'll have to pull in the entire `MVC` with its dependencies to work with Razor.  Razor is built on MVC, so it will require several MVC dependencies to build and perform actions for runtime.

Comment: I need to send email from windows service and to build the email template i am using Razor

Comment: It worked by adding system.web.Razor reference in windows service. thank u :). No other dependent references required in my case.